# Google Cloud Speech use only phrase list in recognition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm using Google Cloud Speech API to recognize person name and surname who i'm calling. Because i have access to Phonebook i have exact Phrase List with all people in phonebook. The problem is when i'm sending data to recognize Speech Api chooses answer now only from my phrase list, he can suggest his own names too.

My goal is to say to speech API for using only my phrase list and select one of this people, not suggest other names.

I watched Speech API and didn't found how can i do it. Maybe someone can help?

Comment: use dialogflow, input your list as intents (batch), so that you can have full control over the speech/conversation

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Speech API there is no way to provide a list of words and get a result only if the word to recognize exists on that list. One way to increase the probability of that word or phrase being recognized is [passing a speechContext](http://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics#phrase-hints), like you did, that contains a list of phrases that act as “hints” to the API.

In your case you can implement that restriction on the client side. This way you should be able to compare the results from the API response with the data on your phonebook.

If you think that this is a feature that is really needed you can [open a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) for the speech API.